# C++ ranged based for loop

Tags: c++

Trying to do something with a ranged based for loop. It can be done with a regular for loop like this:

```
vector<double> sensorReadings(3);
sensorReadings = {0,0,0};

for (int i = 0; i < sensorReadings.size();i++)
{
    sensorReadings[i] += i + 100 ;

}
```

I want to set a vector's first element equal to n (100 in this case) and set every other element equal to n+1. In this case after the above loop runs the vector is 100,101,102, as desired. My problem is doing this with a range base loop always sets all the elements to be the same value. How do I make the above loop into a range based for loop? My attempt is below:

```
vector<double> sensorReadings(3);
sensorReadings = {0,0,0};


for(double &sensorVal: sensorReadings)
{
    double y = 100;
    sensorVal = y;
    y++;
}


for (double i: sensorReadings)
   cout << " " << i ;
```

This loop just sets all values of the vector equal to 100

any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Would be nice if you could try to understand the flow of your program and come up with a solution. It will help you more in the long run.

Comment: Sometimes is very useful to get your hands dirty with a debugger. This is one of those cases in which you find the problem faster than asking others!

Comment: There's a function for this, `std::iota`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
double y = 100;
for(double &sensorVal: sensorReadings)
{
    sensorVal = y;
    y++;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I find that not using a raw loop at all can sometimes be even better. There's a name for the operation you are doing, so the standard library has an algorithm that does just that. It's [`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota)

```
vector<double> sensorReadings(3);
std::iota(begin(sensorReadings), end(sensorReadings), 100);
```

Now there's no need to mentally parse the loop to know what it's doing, nor is there a need to introduce a superfluous variable.